# Changing Vendor Id

Tags: mobile-data

Here's the context: subject - Mobile data (Internet)
I have 4.1 (JellyBean) mobile phone. Everything works great. Of late I happened to travel to UK and my present service operator does not recognize this device for me to use the mobile internet. Everything else works as it should including Wifi but not mobile data.

I was wondering if there is a way to tweak the settings to spoof the device settings to make it impersonate a known device recognizable by my service provider?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a problem with your device model? Perhaps you need to turn on roaming data, or you need to call your carrier to ask them to enable your specific device on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have the wrong APNs. You can try going into System Settings->(More..)Wireless and Networks->Mobile Network Settings->**Access Point Names** and Press the settings button.

This should show the settings menu for the APNs and should have a **Reset to Default** option. Click that and wait for 2-3 minutes. It should start working again hopefully.